# Dynamics 365 Changes tracking - Changes during the call

Tags: ssis, dynamics-365, dynamics-crm-webapi, kingswaysoft

I have a question regarding ChangeTracking.
I have an SSIS package with KingswaySoft, and in my source I pass the input token and I get the Output token. However, I notice that changes made between the time the SSIS component starts reading the CRM data, stores it in the database and returns the Output token, are not taken into account.
An example, I have my SSIS component with the input token at 10:13:16, it starts reading changes at 10:15:08 and returns the OutputToken at 10:15:11. A change that took place at 10:15:10 a.m. was not retrieved in this call and it will not be retrieved during future runs because it is older than the OutputToken received during this call.

Have you ever encountered this?

Thanks